# Algorithm for seating firefighters in vehicle seats

Tags: algorithm, gps

I’m doing a project which involves placing volunteer firefighters, in seats when they arrive at the fire station to take the trucks.

Also some firefighters has drivers license some haven’t and some have a team leader education.

So my idea is to follow them by GPS and send the server a integer of distance to fire station and which education types each has.

Then every 5 sec, run the algorithm and based on the new GPS coordinates change their seats, until 1 is close to the station, and then mark is seat as taken.

This should happen until there is no empty seats or not anymore firefighters to call in or all called firefighters has arrived

The tricky thing I want help with (besides if my idea is the optimal), is to seat the firefighters most optimal.

I was thinking to make a prioritization list of possible roles.
And a prioritization list of vehicles which had to leave the station.

Then take the highest prioritized vehicle and the highest prioritized role, and fill it in with the closest firefighter which has the education.

But then if he is a driver but already set to the teamleaders seat, and only 1 more driver is coming, and there were more teamleaders coming, and two vehicles had to leave, it would be a wrong solution as the second vehicle couldn’t leave.

Again if Drivers and not teamleaders is the highest priority, then if the closest is set as driver, but is also the only one coming with a teamleader education, but more drivers are coming, then it would also be wrong.

Any ideas for the algorithm to work? Or does anybody knows an algorithm for this?

Comment: It's hard to give specific advice without seeing a crisp brute force program. I would point you toward tools for constraint programming.

Comment: Im sure there is an algorithm for this puzzle.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, this type of greedy approach won't necessarily give you an optimal solution.  Have you looked into/heard of Linear Programming or more specifically Integer programming: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming

In short integer programming is one technique for solving these types of scheduling problems.  The problem has some objective you wish to maximise or minimise and is subject to various (linear) constraints.  Integer because we can't have half a volunteer.

From your description the objective function could be to minimise the number of undeployed trucks and the total wait time.  You could have different costs for different trucks to capture the different vehicle priorities.

Constraints would include each vehicle needing at least one driver, at least one team leader and that a volunteer can only be assigned to one vehicle.  There might be other constraints you haven't described as well, such as no one can wait at the base for more than 20 minutes.

If you search for integer programming and scheduling you should find some code examples.  You'll likely need a solver to assist.  Wiki has a fairly comprehensive list, the choice will come down to your programming language preference and budget: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming#Solvers_and_scripting_.28programming.29_languages

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this.. 
as you noticed the only conflicting situation is when you have a firefighter that can be driver and leader.. because the can only occupy one position.. but may be blocking another..

so don't start with them.. first start with the ones that have ether divers license OR Leaders education.. because those already have a predefined seat (the only they can take)..

after those are filled.. assign the ones that can do ether jobs, for the seats that are missing or replace some if they are nearer.

after having a queue of drivers and a queue of leaders.. sort them by distance to the firehouse and assign to trucks in pairs.. then fill the rest of the truck.. removing from a queue by order of ETA..

not sure if it will always give the best solution.. but seems quite optimal.. to to you wish some code? C#?

the question made me curious so. here is the code for what I was talking.. eve if you don't use it

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace FF
{
    class Program
    {
        [Flags]
        public enum Skill
        {
            None = 0,
            Driver = 1,
            TeamLeader = 2,
        }
        public class FireFighter : IComparable<FireFighter>
        {
            public int ID;
            public Skill Skills;//the skills that he has
            public Skill Assigned;//the one that he will be deployed with
            public int ETA;
            public override string ToString()
            {
                return ID + "(" + Skills + ")" + " @ " + ETA + " minutes as " + this.Assigned;
            }


            int IComparable<FireFighter>.CompareTo(FireFighter other)
            {
                return this.ETA.CompareTo(other.ETA);
            }
        }
        public class Truck
        {
            public int ID;
            public int Capacity;
            public List<FireFighter> Crew = new List<FireFighter>();
        }
        static int TotalStationTrucks = 8;
        static List<Truck> Trucks = new List<Truck>();
        static List<FireFighter> Team = new List<FireFighter>();
        static Random Rnd = new Random();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //create the sample data
            int nAvailableSeats = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < TotalStationTrucks; i++)
            {
                Truck oTruck = new Truck();
                oTruck.ID = i;
                nAvailableSeats += oTruck.Capacity = Rnd.Next(4, 7);//seats between 4 - 6
                Trucks.Add(oTruck);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < nAvailableSeats * 2; i++)//add twice the amount of FF we need for all trucks
            {
                FireFighter oFireFighter = new FireFighter();
                oFireFighter.ID = i;
                oFireFighter.ETA = Rnd.Next(Int16.MaxValue);
                Team.Add(oFireFighter);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < Trucks.Count * 2; i++)//add twice the drivers we need
            {
                FireFighter oFireFighter = Team[Rnd.Next(Team.Count)];
                oFireFighter.Skills |= Skill.Driver;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < Trucks.Count * 2; i++)//add twice the leaders we need
            {
                FireFighter oFireFighter = Team[Rnd.Next(Team.Count)];
                oFireFighter.Skills |= Skill.TeamLeader;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < Trucks.Count * 2; i++)//add twice the multitaskers  we need
            {
                FireFighter oFireFighter = Team[Rnd.Next(Team.Count)];
                oFireFighter.Skills = (Skill.TeamLeader|Skill.Driver);
            }
            //Truck that are going to be deployed
            int nTrucksToDeploy = Rnd.Next(2, Trucks.Count);  

            // distribute firefighter by ETA to minimize truck deploy
            //*******************************************************

            //Sort by ETA
            Team.Sort();
            //get top the ones that can only drive
            List<FireFighter> oSelectedDrivers = Team.FindAll(delegate(FireFighter item) { return item.Skills == Skill.Driver; }).GetRange(0, nTrucksToDeploy);
            oSelectedDrivers.ForEach(delegate(FireFighter item) { item.Assigned = Skill.Driver; });

            //get top the ones that can only lead
            List<FireFighter> oSelectedLeaders = Team.FindAll(delegate(FireFighter item) { return item.Skills == Skill.TeamLeader; }).GetRange(0, nTrucksToDeploy);
            oSelectedLeaders.ForEach(delegate(FireFighter item) { item.Assigned = Skill.TeamLeader; });

            //put them on a list of already assigned
            List<FireFighter> oAssigned = new List<FireFighter>();
            oAssigned.AddRange(oSelectedDrivers);
            oAssigned.AddRange(oSelectedLeaders);

            //get the ones that can do ether job 
            List<FireFighter> oMultitaskers = Team.FindAll(delegate(FireFighter item) { return item.Skills == (Skill.Driver | Skill.TeamLeader); });
            //sort by ETA
            oMultitaskers.Sort();
            oAssigned.Sort();
            //put a multitaskers in the queue if he is gonna arrive earlier than the most delayed 
            while (oMultitaskers[0].ETA < oAssigned[oAssigned.Count - 1].ETA)
            { 
                FireFighter oIsOut = oAssigned[oAssigned.Count - 1];
                FireFighter oIsIn = oMultitaskers[0];
                //swap tasks
                oIsIn.Assigned = oIsOut.Assigned;
                oIsOut.Assigned = Skill.None;
                //remove from respective queues
                oAssigned.RemoveAt(oAssigned.Count - 1);
                oMultitaskers.RemoveAt(0);
                //Add the multitasker to queue
                //and if you are questioning if the could get a better solution by choosing another assignment
                //that as no influence.. the optmizing condition is removing the slowest that was on queue
                oAssigned.Add(oIsIn);
                //the out guy is not added for two reasons
                //1st is not a multitasker
                //2nd and most importante.. he was the one with the highest ETA, we will NEVER gain by replacing another driver with this one
                //oMultitaskers.Add(oIsOut); 

                oMultitaskers.Sort();
                oAssigned.Sort();
            }

            //start filling the trucks take one of each from top, wich means the first truck will have the earliest departure
            for (int i = 0; i < nTrucksToDeploy; i++)
            {
                int nDriverIndex = oAssigned.FindIndex(delegate(FireFighter item) { return item.Assigned == Skill.Driver; });
                Trucks[i].Crew.Add(oAssigned[nDriverIndex]);
                oAssigned.RemoveAt(nDriverIndex);
                int nLeaderIndex = oAssigned.FindIndex(delegate(FireFighter item) { return item.Assigned == Skill.TeamLeader; });
                Trucks[i].Crew.Add(oAssigned[nLeaderIndex]);
                oAssigned.RemoveAt(nLeaderIndex);
            }
            //now fill the rest of the crew.. also ordered by ETA
            List<FireFighter> oUnassigned = Team.FindAll(delegate(FireFighter item) { return item.Assigned == Skill.None; });
            oUnassigned.Sort();
            for (int i = 0; i < nTrucksToDeploy; i++)
            {
                while (Trucks[i].Crew.Count < Trucks[i].Capacity)
                {
                    Trucks[i].Crew.Add(oUnassigned[0]);
                    oUnassigned.RemoveAt(0);
                }
            }

            //dump truck data
            Trace.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} trucks to be deployed",nTrucksToDeploy));
            for (int i = 0; i < nTrucksToDeploy; i++)
            {
                Trace.WriteLine(new String('-', 20));
                Truck oTruck = Trucks[i];
                oTruck.Crew.Sort();
                Trace.WriteLine(String.Format("truck {0} estimated time of departure: {1}",oTruck.ID,oTruck.Crew[oTruck.Crew.Count-1].ETA));
                for (int j = 0; j < oTruck.Crew.Count; j++)
                {
                    FireFighter oFireFighter = oTruck.Crew[j];
                    Trace.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}({1})\t @ {2} minutes as \t{3}", oFireFighter.ID, oFireFighter.Skills, oFireFighter.ETA, oFireFighter.Assigned));
                }

            }
            Trace.WriteLine(new String('#', 20));
            //list the team
            for (int i = 0; i < Team.Count; i++)
            {
                FireFighter oFireFighter = Team[i];
                Trace.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}({1})\t @ {2} minutes as \t{3}", oFireFighter.ID, oFireFighter.Skills, oFireFighter.ETA, oFireFighter.Assigned));
            }
        }
    }
}
```